# unable to parse licence file

Tags: php, zend-server, zend-guard

Configured zend server locally every thing installed license but still it shows : `unable to parse licence file!`

[image]

here it is added modules

[image]

Comment: This sounds like you need to contact Zend customer support rather than posting on SO.

Comment: already asked them but they provided license then not any help from them